# Blank view in list

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have to change size of the header view attached with list. The header view is an image. If I increase its size, it works fine. But when I decrease its size, a blank view appears. Here is my code to change the size:

```
 final AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    layoutParams.height = getMyHeight();

                    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This issue appears only on S3 and S4. It works fine on others.